# importing a class from a file in a seprate package

Tags: python, django, python-import

I am using python and django.

my directory structure looks like this

```
hospitality211
  __init__.py
users
  __init__.py
  models.py
venue
  __init__.py
  models.py
```

I am trying to import a class from the model.py file in the venue package into the model.py file in the user package.

I have tried the following

```
from hospitality211.venue.models import Venue
from venue.models import Venue
import venue
```

none of these are working.

I am importing from packages so I am not sure why this is happening

Comment: I expect you have a circular dependency. Does Venue also import User?

Comment: it doesn't but I have my token creation code within venue and imported that from rest framework. That may be the cause. Let me see if moving it fixes it. Thank you

Comment: moved the token code into users and nope still not allowing me to import venue.models

Comment: You should also state exactly why you need to import Venue inside User. If it's just for creating a relationship (eg ForeignKey), note that you can use the string `"appname.ModelName"` rather than the actual model class object, so you may not need to import it at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman that is exactly why I am importing. So this good. Let me experiment with this.

Comment: Do you really have files named `_init_` or `_init_.py`, rather than `__init__.py`?

Comment: of course not. They are proper init files I was just using those for illustration

Comment: How did you code the ForeignKeys, ManyToManys or some sort of relations? can you update the question with your views?

Comment: Post the errors